# How to use PWA in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, pwa

Anyone have an idea how to use PWA (Progressive Web Apps) in Magento2. I have found some blogs but didn't get success.

Comment: Could you share a blog posts you read? And what exactly does not works?

Comment: I am not sure what not working exactly but in future Magento2 coming with PWA. Do you have any guide for that ?

Comment: I have found [interesting qeustion about the PWA](https://community.magento.com/t5/PWA-Theming-Layout-Design/Links-to-PWA-JavaScript-Framework-etc-blogs-add-yours-here/m-p/70548) on the magento forum, it can be helpful.

Comment: Do you have any reference site PWA ? how can I find tihs website built in PWA.

Comment: I dont know no one site on which the PWA was realized :(

Comment: I think Progressive Web Application For Magento2 does not work for ios.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65894/discussion-between-hweb87-and-siarhey-uchukhlebau).

Comment: Why you are thinking so?

Comment: you can see this url https://store.webkul.com/Progressive-Web-Application-For-Magento2.html he is mentioned in it **Note - Progressive Web Application For Magento2 does not work for ios.**

Comment: You can read about the service worker compatibility with a desktop & mobile browsers here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: I used this module from Tigren (https://marketplace.magento.com/tigren-progressivewebapp.html) in Magento 2.1.7 version. It worked just like that without any error. did any one find any way to implement service worker in it please let me know.

Comment: I have installed and configured tigren pwa in.magento 2.2.6 version. My site is SSL secure.
I do have one question. I don't how to check site is working in pwa when open it in mobile. Thank
Sanjay

Answer (score 6):

### About PWA in Magento:

You can read more about [the implementation of the PWA](https://community.magento.com/t5/PWA-Theming-Layout-Design/Links-to-PWA-JavaScript-Framework-etc-blogs-add-yours-here/m-p/70548) on the magento forum, where stored all useful links to a blog post or github projects:

1. Magento 1 [PWA module](https://github.com/meanbee/magento-meanbee-pwa) on github by Meanbee
2. Blog Post ["Why does your Magento Site need to be a Progressive Web App?"](https://www.meanbee.com/news/why-does-your-magento-site-need-to-be-a-progressive-web-app.html) by Tom Robertshaw from Meanbee
3. Magento 2 [Service Worker module](https://github.com/meanbee/magento2-serviceworker) on github by Meanbee
4. Magento 2 [WebApp Manifest module](https://github.com/meanbee/magento2-webappmanifest) on github by Meanbee
5. [Progressive Web Apps post](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) by Google
6. [The Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/?utm_source=devtools#create_the_manifest) by Matt Gaunt & Paul Kinlan

---

### About Service Worker Compatibility:

Usually PWA is realizing using [the Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers). Right now it is not compatible with all browsers:

#### Desktop:

[image: Service Worker Compatibility with desktop browsers]

**Not supported:** IE, Safari

---

#### Mobile:

[image: Service Worker Compatibility with mobile browsers]

**Not supported:** Android Webview, IE, Safari

Comment: That means it's not compatible with iOS

Comment: @hweb87 Right now - yes

Comment: Good extended overview with fresh details https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/244665/2282

Comment: Hi @SiarheyUchukhlebau My question is still open is Magento PWA support in iOS ? Today I have seen bug reported in github https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio/issues/1441

Answer (score 2):

I took word by word from MazePlazza. https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-integrate-progressive-web-app.html#what-is-progressive-web-app-pwa

There are three methods to convert Magento 2 websites to PWA, which are associated with different costs:

1). Magento 2 PWA Extensions: You need to buy the module (up to $150) and pay for the installation service (or install and configure the extension yourself).

2). Magento 2 PWA Studio: You have to hire PWA developers who have strong experience in both Magento 2 and PWA to build your PWA from scratch. It will take up to 6 months to develop your PWA storefront and new API using Magento 2 PWA Studio tools. You should prepare a generous budget for this integration.

3). Magento 2 PWA Theme: Since both PWA storefront and core API were ready built, your cost will mainly depend on your level of customization. This cost would be more reasonable than the second solution and higher than the first solution but it deserves your investment.

According to me, go with the first one

Thank You
Zuber

Comment: If i will go with first option, and i have many third party extensions for my website so Q1. Will it impact on that extensions as well? Q2. Will Magento 2 PWA Extensions support on other third party extensions?

Comment: @BalwantSingh, PWA purchased extension does not affect any of your installed or upcoming extensions. As long as your new page is responsive it will be automatically supported by the PWA extension because PWA purchase extension just needs your page responsive nothing else.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what if i will choose 3rd option still i need PWA developer for the customization?

Comment: @BalwantSingh... yes

Comment: how to start from scratch? is there any step by step guide to implement PWA in magento2.3

Answer (score 1):

I used this module from Tigren (https://marketplace.magento.com/tigren-progressivewebapp.html) in Magento 2.1.7 version. It worked just like that without any error.

Please note that we need to know more about service workers and how to configure them to scale up the applications of the module. At the basic level, it works very well out of the box.

Comment: Hi Kalyan. Me too using the same extension. I followed the installation steps provided. But it shows error.  Can you help me to solve it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Please check my error commands here. https://pastebin.com/8GhESQp3

Comment: Hi @Kalyan, Is the server should be in https?

Comment: 1. Tigren_Core module is not included in the package you downloaded, no need of that. You can ignore it. 2. Yes you need to have https enabled. 3. We tested in our demo server with a dummy SSL certification but not in localhost. 4. Dummy SSL certificate will work well only with firefox if you added as exception, Chrome is strict and PWA won't work with dummy SSL certificate. 5. If you are working in localhost chrome has some flag option to allow SSL in localhost

Comment: Okay. I am using https server, configured correctly as per the installation document.  But still, it is not working.

Comment: I found default tigren's `manifest.json` under `app/code/Tigren/ProgressiveWebApp/view/frontend/web/js/`.
json have default tigren url and data. Is it should be changed?

Comment: Nothing to change at the code level. do you have serviceWorker.js in the root of your project? is that loading along with your page?

Comment: Is there possible to configure PWA in Magento2 without install any extension.

Comment: Of course but I am not much aware of the procedure.

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV Do you have any blog reference how to  to configure PWA in Magento2

Comment: Sorry not at this moment