# Error in PWA Setup in Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, php-7.2, pwa, ubuntu, pwa-studio

We have face error while setup PWA in Magento 2.3.0 with YARN.

See screenshot for more detail

[image]

Magento Version 2.3.0
PHP version 7.2

This error is shown when i try to build using `sudo yarn run build`

I have refer [What is Progressive Web Apps, or PWAs in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244063/what-is-progressive-web-apps-or-pwas-in-magento-2/244665#244665) and [PWA Setup in Magento 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256320/pwa-setup-in-magento-2-3-0/256329#256329)

Answer (score 0):

run this below query. I hope,it would help you

```
yarn run validate-queries
```

after this above query run

```
sudo yarn run build
```