# Data Fetch Error in PWA Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1, pwa, pwa-studio

I tried **PWA** on my localhost it works perfectly but the issue is when I open **Venia** it do not show all the images and also when I click on the **Menu** then it do not show me any **categories** it just showing me `Data Fetch Error` as you guys can see from the images 
[image]

as you guys can see that it shows **Gear** n **training** n its works perfectly but if I click on **Women** or any other category then it just start loading... [image] 
now in the last image it shows me these errors in console.
[image]

Comment: How far did you get in the setup process.  Did you get through this list? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/256329/70343

Comment: Yes @DominicXigen Sir