# Magento 2 PWA Installation for Already existing Magento 2 project

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

Can any guide me how to integrate pwa for already existing magento 2 project without collapsing previous theme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PWA Setup in Magento 2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256320/pwa-setup-in-magento-2-3-0)

Comment: @Subu Did you find any way for this?

Answer (score 2):

Now clone pwa-studio repository

```
git clone https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio.git
```

You have to clone this repository in magento root directory ex: `/var/www/html/magento`

You will see the pwa-studio directory in `/var/www/html/magento`.
Enter into this directoy:

```
cd pwa-studio/
```

Specify the Magento backend server in `.env` file. you can see the `.env.dist` file in
`/var/www/html/magento/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/` direcoty. If you are not
able see, enable show hidden files. Now create .env file from this `env.dist`

```
cp packages/venia-concept/.env.dist packages/venia-concept/.env
```

Open this `.env` file and find `MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL`. Here configure your
local Magento 2 instance, my case it is:

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://magento2-pwa.com/"
```

Find the `deployVeniaSampleData.sh` file in
`/var/www/html/mage0/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/` directory. and copy this
file in your Magento root directory. Now it must look like
`/var/www/html/magento/deployVeniaSampleData.sh` Now run:

```
bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh
```

> After successful installation run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Reference: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/

**I hope this will help**

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will hapen to your existing magento as PWA only needs API's from your Magento store.

Follow all steps mentioned here:
https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

only provide backend URL as your magento link and all data's will be fetched from this link.

Comment: It will change existing frontend theme. I don't want change

Answer (score 1):

1. Choose PWA Solution: Select a PWA solution like Magento PWA Studio, Vue Storefront, or Deity Falcon.
2. Development Environment:** Set up a separate environment for PWA development.
3. Install PWA: Install the chosen PWA solution and configure it to connect with your Magento backend.
4. Customize Theme: Modify the PWA theme to match your existing Magento theme's design.
5. Extension Integration:** Integrate third-party extensions with the PWA if needed.
6. Data Migration: Ensure customer data and orders are synchronized between the existing site and PWA.
7. Testing: Thoroughly test the PWA for compatibility, responsiveness, and performance.
8. Progressive Enhancement: Add advanced features to the PWA gradually.
9. Launch and Monitor: Launch the PWA to a limited audience, monitor performance, then roll it out to all users.
10. Expert Assistance: Consider working with experienced developers for a successful integration.