# Magento 2 PWA installation in Localhost

Tags: magento2, pwa

I have followed this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282217/magento-2-pwa-installation-for-already-existing-magento-2-project) for PWA installation for the already existing Magento 2.4.3 version.

When I tried to run the below command then we are facing an error.

```
yarn run build
```

Error :

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn venia run build
$ yarn workspace @magento/venia-concept run build
$ yarn run build:prod
$ yarn run clean && webpack --no-progress --env.mode production
$ rimraf dist
Error: Internal server error (... 1 errors total)
    at /Sites/localhost/magento2/demo24/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:48:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async getPossibleTypes (/Sites/localhost/magento2/demo24/pwa-studio/packages/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:122:18)
    at async module.exports (/Sites/localhost/magento2/demo24/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/webpack.config.js:77:27)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/local/bin/node
Arguments: /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.10/libexec/lib/cli.js run build
Directory: /Sites/localhost/magento2/demo24/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have already set the backend URL in the packages/venia-concept/.env file.

Please let me know what's wrong with this.

Comment: which command did you execute in pwa-studio directory?

Comment: I am executing yarn run build command.

Comment: Did you executed yarn install or yarn create @magento/pwa?

Comment: I have executed yarn install and followed below link
https://webscoot.io/blog/magento-pwa-guide/

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am getting the same issue please help me.

Comment: @SnehaPanchal its still open

Comment: @SanjayJethva when you got the solutions please mention here so that it will be helpful for others