# Magento 2.3 PWA Studio How to Setup Locally?

Tags: magento2.3, pwa, venia

Magento 2, How to setup locally pwa studio for testing purpose only and please describe the pwa steps.I have used xampp with php 7.2.19 version.

Thanks.

Comment: pwa work on https only

Comment: I have set locally https

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Progressive Web Apps, or PWAs in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244063/what-is-progressive-web-apps-or-pwas-in-magento-2)

Comment: Hello @MohitKumarArora , In your link where define the set locally ?

Comment: Hi @HardikMakwana, If you check the answer from Aditya Shah, you will find the details.

Comment: Kindly follow Steps given in below link
https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

Answer (score 1):

Currently Magento have launched pwa-studio, but there is a theme on which Magento is working currently name "Venia".

You may find the steps described by Magento itself on this link (https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/).

You can simply colne from the repo and get to work. Let us know in case if you face any issue to do so further.

@Edit:
If using windows it is recommended to use docker.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Narendra Vyas

Thank you for your answer.But i am get the error in setup upgrade.Please refer the following screenshot link:
https://www.screencast.com/t/yevaZuU5O0OQ

Comment: @Hardik: using windows ? If so its preferred to use a docker, else you may get various errros ?

Comment: By looking at the error it seems as if there is some issue in Magento and not in pwa. May be you are getting error in s:upgrade.

Comment: I am using windows.
can you please provide me some reference links

Comment: the link in the answer returns 404

Answer (score 1):

Magento PWA Studio v5.0.0 released last month introduced a new handy command @magento/create-pwa which helps you set up a PWA project way easier.

We did try different ways before this command was in place, but using @magento/create-pwa appears to be the easiest option to set up an initial PWA Studio project structure using the Venia storefront as a template.

We put together a step-by-step guide [here](https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/how-to-create-custom-pwa-project-on-top-magento-pwa-studio) which takes advantage of that new @magento/create-pwa command, you can give it a try. Hope it saves you time when exploring PWA Studio.