# Mgento2: How to install PWA Studio

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pwa, pwa-studio

I am trying to install Magento 2.3 with PWA studio, but when I am not getting the right steps.

Can you explain for this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Progressive Web Apps, or PWAs in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244063/what-is-progressive-web-apps-or-pwas-in-magento-2)

Comment: @Shiwani Have you fulfilled the prerequisites for The PWA installation(Node, Python and Yarn installation)?

Comment: Installation and configuration of PWA studio required expertise in Linux to properly setup the environment. I think the steps by WebKul is enough to setup PWA vania storefront. https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/

Answer (score 2):

## How to setup Magento PWA Locally?

Prerequisites:

-PHP 7.2

-Node 10.16.0

-NodeJS 10.16.0

-NPM 6.9.0

-Yarn 1.16.0

- Install Fresh Magento2.3.1
- Remove If Existing Nodejs & Npm are installed then run following commands
- sudo apt-get remove nodejs
- sudo apt-get remove npm
- To install Node 10.16.0 run following commands
      Ref : (https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)
- curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash - sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
- sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
- You can check Node & Npm Version
- node -v
- npm -v
- Now clone the source code of PWA Studio. Run the commands in magento root folder 
      (Ex: /var/www/html/magentopwa/)
- Go to /var/www/html/magentopwa/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept
- Copy deployVeniaSampleData.sh file in magento root and run command
- bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh (Ex: /var/www/html/magentopwa/) It installed the Venia Sample Data
- Once the Venia Sample Data is installed then run following commands
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- How to install Venia Sample Data? -Ref: [https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/install-sample-data/](https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/install-sample-data)
- cd pwa-studio
- run yarn install (If any errors run yarn install --ignore-engines ) 
      -Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45088031/how-to-ignore-incompatible-engine-node-error-on-installing-npm-dependencies-wi?rq=1
- Go to /var/www/html/magentopwa/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept
- Copy and paste .env.dist file and rename .env
- Change url MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="http://127.0.0.1/magentopwa/"
- run sudo yarn run build
- yarn run watch:venia
- Open the url in new window
      Url Ex: https://magento-venia-concept-6ffqd.local.pwadev:10000/

Comment: @Varjesh when i clone pwa on root folder. I am not getting .env dist file.   ----------Under the packages/venia-concept directory, copy .env.dist into a new .env file:

Comment: @Shiwani You can use this .env file. Url : https://tinyurl.com/y4wbbr9r

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below url, i was done with this step

https://blog.landofcoder.com/detailed-tutorial-magento-2-3-pwa-studio-installation/

I hope its work for you.

Comment: with this link i struck at symlinks.How to create symlinks in windows.can you brief on this

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow this link. It has complete process to install pwa

https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

Answer (score 0):

*Kindly follow below link. I have successfully completed PWA setup using this tutorial. It's fully tested and working solution.*

https://devhooks.in/blog/magento-pwa-sudio-installation-guide

**Hope it'll help you too.**