# How to install Venia and magento in local environment?

Tags: magento2.3.4

I want to setup venia as storefront and backend as magento how I can do ?Any good guidelines ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244063/what-is-progressive-web-apps-or-pwas-in-magento-2